# PyQt5 - How to animate QGraphicsItem?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem

How to properly add animation on QGraphicsItem? 
In C++ I can inherit QObject and QGraphicsItem so I can use QPropertyAnimation, but PyQt doesn't allow to inherit from 2 Qt classes.
QPropertyAnimation is also obsolete in PyQt5.

Comment: Just inherit from [`QGraphicsObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: "QPropertyAnimation is also obsolete in PyQt5." Huh? It is? Reference?